# Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571) when using map()

Tags: typescript, function

Although I have googled this error and seen many posts about the topic, I still couldn't figure out how to fix the error.

Straight to the example, I have data that looks like that:

```js
const earthData = {
  distanceFromSun: 149280000,
  continents: {
    asia: {area: 44579000, population: 4560667108},
    africa: {area: 30370000, population: 1275920972},
    europe: {area: 10180000, population: 746419440},
    america: {area: 42549000, population: 964920000},
    australia: {area: 7690000, population: 25925600},
    antarctica: {area: 14200000, population: 5000}
  }
}
```

I want to create a new object in which *keys* are continents names, and *values* are areas. I can easily do the following and it works well:

```js
const outputWorks = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(earthData.continents).map( ([k, o]) => [k, o.area] ))
// {
//   "asia": 44579000,
//   "africa": 30370000,
//   "europe": 10180000,
//   "america": 42549000,
//   "australia": 7690000,
//   "antarctica": 14200000
// }
```

By contrast, a very similar code doesn't work when the *same* input data is a result of a different operation.

```js
const solarSystem = {
  mercury: {},
  venus: {},
  earth: { // earth entry is just like `earthData` object
    distanceFromSun: 149280000,
    continents: {
      asia: { area: 44579000, population: 4560667108 },
      africa: { area: 30370000, population: 1275920972 },
      europe: { area: 10180000, population: 746419440 },
      america: { area: 42549000, population: 964920000 },
      australia: { area: 7690000, population: 25925600 },
      antarctica: { area: 14200000, population: 5000 },
    },
  },
  mars: {},
  jupiter: {},
  saturn: {},
  uranus: {},
  neptun: {},
};
```

```js
const earthDataExtracted = Object.values(solarSystem)[2] as any; // again, this is the same as `earthData`
```

So why does the following throw an error?

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(earthDataExtracted.continents).map( ([k, o]) => [k, o.area] ))
//                                                                                    ^
```

> (parameter) o: unknown
>
> Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)

[See here for TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgQwE5QBYBEFQTAvDAbwFgAoGGAEwEtoExg4AxJEAWwGUBXMALhgEYALAE4ATAA4ADNMkAaUuVBgoVMHGUQ%20xMuRgIIVBFuSI%20gwQFYA7MJmyYABxAPOAGyxVwZiwDZJPnyt%20SXEAX3kdcgQAMyQqYCNCE0SAZkkUqxk5R2c3Dy8BUSsLMUlhK1FwhV04ThYHOGMkUwFJfik7HJd3FQKrQR9BfmFzSSrIvVY4OISmlsFRCxFOp2783hhhQdKZcd09TmgkBFdDOcSrH1sV3J7PDcWxX2k93TpsJGAVWaTmxKFRFlsqs8r0NhZdtVQqRoSRSEpoDBmhA8DAAPIAIwAVnAvgA6WJsACiyjicAgAApMTj8eooGTKYgUBgsAg8UoVGoNABKPGsBAOCkwCkAbQA1vYQABdbl4AB8MHFkrxySlMG5soA9JqAO4gJBilHRVRwUhmkgI2AQEDuJDsACe0DgrFR2nIU0%20dXtWleADd1IcfRFyEy0FpquRqLR6EwWBxuHwhGIOtJg7oOSaNOGJlEDIkCHo-mZLDYbmswd4-AEgiEYK99jEZvnCy00hksvYQXcCvwiiVAeVRHW0-tavVGoQW-82ingbd1nx%20oNhqNhxG3h74s3kmZFstU11Qfc%20FsRICZGucwcjiczpOdzBLtcD12FzBHos-JJL-sospkF8W5aFOiYLECnbzhWMAQtIP66K8rz8kgmiEK8WKcA4VBQNMQbVBAWB1BsBCvHUdCBqhaZqA4UAJhRMIANzmpa8DIGgmDYESAAe9IIF8cAUKi1K4lAeK%20icnDkhS1q2g6TqsNyIqiGq%20h6GA9qMSQQn4oSrAkvSVCSVpIl0gyFKhiyHHcccfEUOy4CcnSEC8vygrCkqMDSrKuAKu5IAqn8aoajA2rwEgLBIDAqDTHAQA)

And even more strangely, on my own machine (VSCode) the error is different:

> Property 'area' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Is there a simple thing I'm missing here?

Comment: Why are you asserting it to be `any` instead of `typeof earthData`?  Once you do `Object.entries(x)` where `x` is of type `any`, you're going to get `Array<[string, unknown]>`.  For that matter, why `Object.entries(solarSystem)[2]` instead of `solarSystem.earth`?  The compiler has no idea what the former will be (it doesn't keep track of object property *order*) while the latter is easy.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks. I use `Object.entries(solarSystem)[2]` and not `solarSystem.earth` because the index (`2`) is figured out in a computation and I don't know it from the outset.

Comment: I don't think I'd recommend any code that depends on property order; if you're using `Object.entries()` you might as well store things in the array to begin with.  But anyway, let's say you are handed `earthDataExtracted` and the compiler doesn't know what type it is (because all it knows is that it's *some* value). Then you should tell it the right type (e.g., `{ continents: Record<string, { area: number, population: number }> };`) as opposed to `any` if you want better behavior, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAjlBW), for example. Does that address your issue or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz, you're not missing anything, it's my too-minimal example that oversimplifies my real data. In the context of this current example, consider that I have many more properties than just `area` and `population`, and each of those other properties is likely to nest some more objects. So asserting the type as you suggest -- by laying out the entire data structure -- would be too painful.

Comment: Hmm, could you make the code a [mre] that at least gives a flavor of the issue with too many properties?  I'd suggest `as typeof solarSystem.earth` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpgy6N) but you don't know that it's at the `earth` key. Surely somewhere in your code you have the types of the values you're dealing with, right? Is there no `interface` or something that represents these things? Without a more evocative example I don't know how to propose an answer you'd accept.

Comment: Does only `earth` contain a `continents` property? If so you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m352Aw).  There needs to be some way to use information the compiler already has to specify the type here.

Comment: Do you need to work around the error or to understand it?

Comment: @Ben, currently I just need to work around it. The comments by jclaz showed me the path to understanding, but right now I'd be happy with just circumventing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve the issue, you need to either provide a type for `earthDataExtracted.continents` (but if I understand correctly your discussion with @jcalz, it not that easy), or simply declare it as `any`:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(earthDataExtracted.continents).map( ([k, o]: [string, any]) => [k, o.area] ))
```